# Space Consumption for SQL Index Rebuild

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, index

I am attempting to rebuild the indexes for a single table on a SQL Server 2005 reporting database.  The indexes are heavily fragmented as this has not been done for a long time.  I am running the following query...

```
ALTER INDEX ALL ON Table_A REBUILD
```

Before building the index, the data is consuming 32 GB and the indexes 98 GB.  I am unable to finish the rebuild as I am running out of space once the rebuild consumes an additional 80 GB.

Is there any way to determine how much space I will need to rebuild the indexes on this table (and eventually all tables within my db)?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to know exact size (1.5 is the rule of thumb as @Aaron Bertrand points out).  You might try rebuilding one index at a time instead of all of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typical wisdom is 1.5x index size, plus a little fudge depending on fill factor and how full your current index pages are (in most cases I would expect it to be slightly less than 1.5x). But I would definitely not cut it close. If you don't have 150GB free on your drive, I would find a way to do it elsewhere. I don't know if `WITH DROP_EXISTING` will help here, somehow I don't think so.

Comment: Perfect, just looking for a rule of thumb.  I am pushing to obtain some additional drive space and need to have some idea of what I'd need at a minimum.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using index all - have you tried rebuilding individual indexes one at a time?

Comment: Its a good idea and I thought about it, but you can't regain the space consumed when rebuilding the indexes and still keep the indexes in a defragmented state.